# Connect to vBulletin database from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vbulletin

I'm having some trouble finding the right approach for this problem.

**Background**
I'm developing an application using Ruby on Rails and I have to query a vBulletin database to fetch, for example, the last posts.
The forum is not mantained by me, but I can ask the owners for information.

**Problem**
The problem is I can't find a vBulletin API or ruby gem that allows a connection to the database and I'm not getting useful results from my google searches.

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/lloydpick/vbulletin

Hopefully this will help. Checking GitHub is always a good starting point.

Comment: Sure as hell it is! also please remember to refine your question as "any API or gem" doesn't really narrow it down. thanks!

Comment: I took a look a it, but the problem is that is Mechanize to mock user movement and it doesn't work with newer versions

Comment: /\/\ take a look at the first four links in the link I just posted. Perhaps one of those will help

Comment: I had already seen those, but I had trouble imprementing them. Anyways it seems there's not other option that keep trying with github projects, I'll wait some time to accept the answer just in case something else comes up. Thanks!

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be one, you could always just make your own using something like `rest-client` if vBulletin has an API. Otherwise, you're just sorta screwed and have to scrape the page.